# RMarkdown / quarto format independent figure reference

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I think I have tried every combination, and remain stumped.

I have a Quarto source ...
{#fig:mediatablocation }

and cannot figure out how to refer to that target. I have tried:

- v1 (@mediatablocation)
- v2 @mediatablocation
- v3 @fig:mediatablocation
- v4 (@fig:mediatablocation)
- v5 @ref(fig:mediatablocation) -- this is what chatgpt recommended

and I want a solution that works for both html and pdf. Recommendations?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The reference in the text should simply be @fig-my-figure

And the figure inclusion text should look like this:
{#fig-my-figure width=50% }

You might not need the width parameter but specifying that wrongly can break the figure reference (see point 3 below).

A few things can cause this to break, which were part of my problem.

1. There must be a blank line after the inclusion instruction
2. The figure reference name must begin with "fig-"
3. If you have additional parameters, such as width, don't comma separate them.